# how to get product list of specified category using rest API?

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I want to access specified product list. for example access all the products in Jacket's category.

Comment: Have you try and code? Or you want know from scratch?

Answer (score 8):

**You can get the list of products of specific categories using search criteria concept of rest api.**

**Below is the url for that .**

> www.yoururl/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&
> searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=2&
> searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=created_at&
> searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=DESC&
> searchCriteria[pageSize]=10& searchCriteria[currentPage]=1

**Here i am getting products which having category id : 2**

**Here Id 2 is for jacket.**

**Same way you can pass your category id with the given criteria.**

### Authorization Header

Remember to inform the `Authorization` header.
It must contain `Bearer`  + `admin token`.
The admin token can be obtained with the following request:
`curl -X POST 'https://YOURMAGENTOURL.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token' \ -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \ --data-raw '{ "username": "YOURADMINUSERNAME", "password": "YOURADMINPASS" }'`

Comment: Can you please elaborate in details..

Comment: @AdityaShah - Happy to help and keep helping :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dedicated REST API from Magento 2.
Your need can be satisfied by calling following URL:

```
http://yoururl/rest/V1/categories/$categoryId/products
```